# Saving the content of data into csv - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, csv

Hi I'm trying to save the content of data which came from my webserver into csv file.

I'm trying this code which came from various question here in stackoverflow.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success) {
        console.log(data);
        var saving = document.createElement('a');

        saving.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
        saving.download = 'Summary.csv';
        saving.click();
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error in downloading!');

});
```

But the content of data doesn't save into my `summary.csv` and gave me this 
`[object object]`. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What does the console show is the format of `data`? Can you post an example? At the very least, is it an array or an object?

Comment: hi @GregL , it gave me this: Object {result: Array[218], success: true}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that `encodeURIComponent()` requires a string, and you are giving it an object, so it calls `.toString()` on it, which is why you get `[object Object]`.

Instead, you need to convert your data array into a CSV string yourself. If you are using [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) you can use `d3.csv.format(rows)`, which is very nice. Or you can find another JS CSV library. Or you can use the following very simplistic implementation I just wrote for you:

```
function csv(arr) {
    var ret = [];
    ret.push('"' + Object.keys(arr[0]).join('","') + '"');
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        var line = [];
        for (var key in arr[i]) {
            if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                line.push('"' + arr[i][key] + '"');
            }
        }
        ret.push(line.join(','));
    }
    return ret.join('\n');
}
```

> **NB:** This function assumes you pass it a valid array with at least one element, and all the elements are objects with *exactly* the same keys. If none of these assumptions are true for you, either extend my function or use a more robust third party library.

So, putting this all together, your final code would be:

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success) {
        console.log(data);
        var saving = document.createElement('a');

        saving.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csv(data.results));
        saving.download = 'Summary.csv';
        saving.click();
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error in downloading!');
});
```

Note that I needed to access `data.results` to get the actual array of results. And I am assuming you will use my `csv()` function or another similar one to convert the array into a CSV string.

Answer (score 1):

add append the saving to work in firefox!!

```
... // as is written
saving.download = 'Summary.csv';
document.body.appendChild(saving);
saving.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-csv

```
<button type="button" ng-csv="ExportCsv()" filename="ExportCsv.csv" csv-header="['a','b']" charset="utf-8">CSV</button>
$scope.ExportCsv= async function(){
  const msg = await getdata();
  return msg;
}
var getdata =  function abc(a,b) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    $http.get(// use backend)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.datacsv =[];angular.forEach($scope.dt, function (value,key) {
             $scope.datacsv.push({"a":value.a,"b":value.b});
                           
          });
                
      })
    setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve($scope.datacsv);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```